# How do I get an Aspara Video playauth?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I'm trying to use Aspara Video to distribute videos in China. I've uploaded videos into Alibaba Cloud and have got the standard HTML code below.

```
<head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >
              <meta name="viewport"   content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
              <title>Vod</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="//g.alicdn.com/de/prismplayer/2.6.0/skins/default/aliplayer-min.css" />
              <script type="text/javascript" src="//g.alicdn.com/de/prismplayer/2.6.0/aliplayer-min.js"></script>
              </head>
              <body>
              <div  class="prism-player" id="J_prismPlayer"></div>
              <script>
                var player = new Aliplayer({
                  id: "J_prismPlayer",
                  autoplay: true,
                  width:"1920px",
                  height:"1280px",
                  vid:"<--video-id-->",
                  playauth:'',
                  cover:''
                });
              </script>
            </body>
```

In order for the HTML code to work, there needs to be a 'playauth' code. I am not sure where to locate this code and cannot find any guidance on the Alibaba help site.

UPDATE - Alibaba support have told me to instead use this code for Prismplayer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport"   content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
     <title>User test case</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//g.alicdn.com/de/prismplayer/2.7.1/skins/default/aliplayer-min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//g.alicdn.com/de/prismplayer/2.7.1/aliplayer-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div  class="prism-player" id="J_prismPlayer" style="position: absolute"></div>
        <script>
            var player = new Aliplayer({
            id: 'J_prismPlayer',
            width: '100%',
            autoplay: false,
            //Supports playing based on a stream playback address, which has the highest priority.
            source: 'stream play URL',
            //Playback method 2: recommended for VOD users
            vid : '1e067a2831b641db90d570b6480fbc40',
            playauth : '',
            cover: 'http://liveroom-img.oss-cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/logo.png',            
            //Playback method 3: only applicable to MPS users
            vid : '1e067a2831b641db90d570b6480fbc40',
            accId: '',
            accSecret: '',
            stsToken: '',
            domainRegion: '',
            authInfo: '',
            //Playback method 4: based on STS
            vid : '1e067a2831b641db90d570b6480fbc40',
            accessKeyId: '',
            securityToken: '',
            accessKeySecret: ''
            },function(player){
                console.log('The player has been created.')
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This has allowed me to play videos using the 'play stream URL' feature. However, this appears to not enable features such as subtitles and resolution selector, which is the whole reason I am using Aspara. From what I've read in the documentation, this requires the 'Playauth' id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the playauth ID by using either API or SDK.

**Let me highlight how to get the playauth ID using API:**

Request Example:

```
http://vod.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/?Action=GetVideoPlayAuth&VideoId=1234&Format=JSON
```

Response:

```
 {
     "RequestId": "123456",
     "VideoMeta": {
         "VideoId": "98756",
         "Title": "Alibaba Cloud VOD",
         "Status": "Normal"
      },
      "PlayAuth": "sstyYuew678999ew90000000xtt7TYUh"
    }
```